# Post method with retrofit never trigger in OnResponse or in OnFailure

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to do a post with retrofit to check if some data exist in the server. My problem is that nver go throught onResponse or OnFailure. The code never pass in this two methods. I don't get any error in the log. If I debug, the code stop here: call.enqueue(new Callback() and in the next step go outside the method.

Some help will be appreciate

Code:

```
 ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<User> call = apiService.smsPincodeCheck(getPhoneNuber, email);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(response.code() == 401){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "401", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Interface:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/check")
    Call<User> smsPincodeCheck(@Field("email") String email,  @Field("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

User model:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private final static String TAG = "User";

    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private Long id;
    private Long commerceId;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String dni;
    private String companyCharge;
.
.
. Getters and setters
```

JSON:

This is the json that I'm trying to send to the server:

```
{
  "phoneNumber" : "444444444", 
  "email" : "example@example.com"
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
Call<ResponseSMS> call = apiService.smsPincodeCheck(getPhoneNuber, email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSMS>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Response<ResponseSMS> response) {
            if(response.isSuccess()){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(response.code() == 401){
                Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "401", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSMS> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Interface:

```
Call<ResponseSMS> smsPincodeCheck(@Field("email") String email, @Field("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

Model:

```
public class ResponseSMS {
    public String response;
    public int status;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saying that you are trying to send JSON, but your Retorift interface describes that your are trying to send form

Comment: After your web service call, what type of data are you returning from server? Is that data relates with `User` model.

Comment: How can I send a Json with my interface?? The server is not returning nothing.

Comment: But I know that the serve should be returning something, because I can check the call with postman and get the respone

Comment: whats the response? Does postman showing any type of response like `{response : "Success"}` or something like that?

Comment: @RahulThe code never go throught the response

Comment: stop here: call.enqueue(new Callback<User>()  and go out of the method directly

Comment: Yes, if the user exist {response : "Success"} if not, status: 401. But in my android code don't show nothing. Seems that for some reason the method onResponse or onFailure never are trigged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you will need to make a separate model class to handle response of your web service :

`public class Response {
public String response;
public int status;
}`

and put this class in place of `User` in your retrofit web service call.

Replace `User` with `Response` in :
 1. Your `smsPincodeCheck` method of `ApiInterface` Interface.
 2. `Call<Response> call = apiService.smsPincodeCheck(getPhoneNuber, email);`
 3.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(response.code() == 401){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterThreeActivity.this, "401", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You mean call.enqueue(new Callback<Respone>() instead call.enqueue(new Callback<User>()??

Comment: yep, try to change that. You also need to change `User` with `Response` in your `smsPincodeCheck` method of `ApiInterface` Interface.

Comment: This is not working. With your changes, I have an incompatible types:      Call<Response> smsPincodeCheck(@Body User user);
        Call<User> call = apiService.smsPincodeCheck(user);

Comment: I've updated my questions with your suggestions. You can see in EDIT part, same problem. Code don't trigger onResponse or onFailure

Comment: Hi @Rahul. I've found the solution with your help. Please, add this changes in your answer. I need to put @SerializedName("email") and @SerializedName("phoneNumber") in my user Class.